# Why does HDR setting automatically turns OFF?

Tags: nikon, hdr, nikon-d5600

I am using Nikon D5600. At times I noticed this feature is disabled and sometimes it is enabled. When it is enabled and set to OFF, I enable it and capture a photo. When I recheck, it is set to OFF again.

1. When does this feature gets enabled ? Is it related to RAW + Fine ?
2. How to keep it enabled unless I manually turn OFF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDR (High Dynamic Range) is designed to switch off after each use. It also doesn't work in any RAW mode.

This is in the [D5600 Reference Manual](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/T2D6s009HCPw03w5wYS97chunQ10/D5600RM_(En)04.pdf) on page 138/139

> It can not be used to record NEF (RAW) images.

> HDR turns off automatically after the photograph is taken;

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only two frames? Bummer. Most cameras with built-in HDR give three, with a user selectable 1,2, or 3 stops between frames. My Canons also give the option to leave it on or turn it off automatically, rather than forcing the auto turnoff.

Comment: @MichaelC if you shoot bracketed rather than HDR you have all the choices you mention, it just then means the camera won't HDR it all nice & pretty in a jpg for you - you do it in the computer instead.

Comment: Yeah, but having those choices in-camera, and being able to save each raw frame (or each raw+JPEG frame) in addition to getting an in-camera composite is nice, too. Too bad Nikon doesn't give that flexibility to the D5x00 series. A while back I shot a little real estate work and being able to deliver dozens of decent HDR images without spending hours at the computer was the difference between making it worth it for what it paid and making it not worth the time it would have taken the old way.

Comment: Indeed it would be nice - but I guess they've got to keep some of the selling points for the high-end cameras, or everybody would just use the cheap stuff;)